# Extracting numbers from varchar column for calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column of patient height data, stored as `varchar` type, in SQL Server.

Values are stored in this format:

| <tab_name> |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 5 ft |
| 65 in |
| 5 ft 10 in |
| 4 ft 5.25 in |

There are instances of bad data too, such as 70, 5 ft 9 in, but that is far from the norm, some instances of 4'5" which I've used an initial query to replace the ' with ft and " with in to normalize.

What I need to do is convert the data into just numeric format, my output will have two columns, one for the actual numeric value, and the other for units.

The issue that I'm running into is that I get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Here's what I have attempted thus far, which clearly isn't working.

```
CASE 
    WHEN newvalue LIKE '%ft%in%' 
        THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), TRIM(LEFT(newvalue, PATINDEX('%f%', newvalue) - 1)))
    WHEN newvalue LIKE '%ft%' 
        THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), TRIM(LEFT(newvalue, PATINDEX('%f%', newvalue) - 1)))
    ELSE 0
END AS [ft value]
```

The end goal of course is to do something like [ft value]*12 + [in value] for instances where the data is in feet and inches.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why not fix your design to start with? Then you won't have data that could be implied to mean you have a customer that is 60' tall.

Comment: Expected a comment like this :), it’s not my database, it’s another vendor and my responsibility is to extract the data. If you have a suggestion for how to deal with it, I’m all ears.

Comment: Is this a one-off job? If so you might be better off just pulling out the distinct values and working out a mapping to stick in a case statement. With height there are only going to be so many possible values, far quicker for you to work out what they mean than to teach your SQL query how to read a free-text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an option (without much testing)

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('60')
,('5 ft')
,('65 in')
,('5 ft 10 in')
,('4 ft 5.25 in')
     
Select A.SomeCol
      ,B.InInches
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select InInches = sum( value) 
                  From (
                        Select value = try_convert(decimal(10,4),value)
                                       * case when lead(value,1) over (order by [key]) like '%ft%' then 12 else 1 end 
                         From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' )
                       ) B1
             ) B
```

**Resutls**

```
SomeCol         InInches
60              60.0000
5 ft            60.0000
65 in           65.0000
5 ft 10 in      70.0000
4 ft 5.25 in    53.2500
```

**More Performant, but has more Risk**

```
Select A.*
      ,InInches = (Pos1*Pos2) +(Pos3*Pos4)
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Pos1 = coalesce(try_convert(decimal(10,4),JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')),1.0)
                      ,Pos2 = coalesce(try_convert(decimal(10,4),JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')),1.0)
                      ,Pos3 = coalesce(try_convert(decimal(10,4),JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]')),0.0)
                      ,Pos4 = coalesce(try_convert(decimal(10,4),JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]')),0.0)
                 From  ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(replace([SomeCol],'ft','12'),'in','1'),' ','","')+'"]' )  ) B1(S)
             ) B
```

Comment: Thanks John! While this works to solve my initial problem, upon further exploration of the dataset I realized I'd have similar problems with other data elements (weight, blood pressure, respiration, etc). Ended up going with a Python solution to do all the manipulation, and just exported the data natively from the DB. But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: @mtaa_hl7 Fair enough.   Pleased you found a solution